# Firebase SDK for Swift, Not automatically sending events

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, google-analytics-firebase

I've created an Swift App using SwiftUI lifecycle.

I followed the instruction [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#swift_1)

I installed Firebase SDK using Xcode not CocoaPods.

What I wanted is that Firebase send an event whenever a user open a "View".

Here is my code snippet.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
struct my_App: App {
            
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

and another file for a view.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAnalytics


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

However, When I add `Analytics.logEvent("CustomView", parameters: nil)` to ContentView.

Firebase sends the event data.

Is there an argument to set to automatically send event whenever a View is appeared?

Thanks

Comment: No, you will need to send the events in `.didAppear` modifier. With UIKit you could create a UIViewController subclass that reported an event and the subclass that for all of your view controllers, but SwiftUI uses structs, so there is no inheritance.  Further, SwiftUI views often contain many nested subviews. How would firebase know which views should send an event and which shouldn't?

Comment: @Paulw11 Understood. Then as you said, sending the events manually is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the FirebaseAnalyticsSwift target to the project. (See https://www.kiloloco.com/articles/010-add-package-product-xcode/) and add `import FirebaseAnalyticsSwift` to the source.

See the implementation at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift/Sources/Analytics%2BSwiftUI.swift.

**Update (November 2023):** As of Firebase 10.17.0, the FirebaseAnalyticsSwift APIs are now available via FirebaseAnalytics and it is no longer necessary to separately add FirebaseAnalyticsSwift.